# Need help understanding chained observables

Tags: angular, observable

I am working with observables and I'm struggling to understand how to work with them in loops.

In my project we load a list of parts and then we loop over each of those parts and for each iteration of the loop we need to request a resource which needs to wait for the server to respond before applying that resource. Once that is done it should move to the next iteration, finally once all iterations of the loop are complete the observable should be complete and the app allowed to continue. However the app isn't waiting for all of the iterations of the loop to complete before moving forward.

Here's an example of the code I'm thinking of (note this is Angular 2).

```
public load(): void {
  this.loadParts(this.parts).subscribe(() => {
    // This code should wait to run until all of these observables are complete. However for some reason I get here before I get to the code inside the httpService.get observable inside the loadMaterial method below.
  }
}

private loadParts(parts: Part[]): Observable<any> {
  Observable.create((observer: any) => {
    for(part of parts) {
      this.applyMaterial(part.material).subscribe();
    }
    // This observer should be completed when the for loop is done and all materials have been applied.
    observer.next();
    observer.complete();
  });
}

private applyMaterial(material: Material[]): Observable<any> {
  this.loadMaterial(material.id).subscribe(() => {
    // We need to request the material from the server and wait for the response before applying it here.
  }
}

private loadMaterial(materialId: String): Observable<any> {
  this.httpService.get(API.LoadMaterialsURL + '/' + materialId).subscribe((response: any) => {
    // Update the material service to include the material data returned by the response.
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your code:

- You `subscribe` too often. You should stick to transforming/chaining the original observable as long as possible and only subscribe at the end, from the code consuming the observable (i.e. the code that needs to use the values the observable emits).
- All of your methods lack a `return` statement, which means NONE of them returns an observable.

Here's a rough outline showing how you can chain operators until you obtain the data you want:

```ts
const partIds = [1, 2, 3, 4];

const materialsObs = Observable.from(partIds)

  // load the part for a given part id
  .mergeMap(partId => this.http.get(`http://api.com/part/${partId}`))

  // extract the material id from the loaded part
  .map(loadedPart => loadedPart.material.id)

  // load the material for a given material id
  .mergeMap(materialId => this.http.get(`http://api.com/material/${materialId}`));
```

The key is to use the `mergeMap()` operator every time you need to pass a value to another observable.

Then, you only subscribe ONCE, when you actually need to use the final values:

```ts
materialsObs.subscribe(material => console.log(material));
```